# Minimize the sum of solution of linear equation

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, linear-algebra

Let x(i,j) be a variable. All variables and constants can only have value of 0 or 1. Also, sum of two variables x(i,j) and x(k,l) is equal to `(x(i,j)+x(k,l)) % 2`   For a given equation of the following format, what algorithm can be used to find a solution to all x(i,j) such that sum of all x(i,j) is minimized:

```
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +x(1,0)  +0       +0       +x(2,0)  +0       +0       = 0
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +0       +x(1,1)  +0       +0       +x(2,1)  +0       = 0
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +0       +0       +x(1,2)  +0       +0       +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,0)  +0       +0       +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,0)  +0       +0       = 0
0       +x(0,1)  +0       +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +0       +x(2,1)  +0       = 0
0       +0       +x(0,2)  +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +0       +0       +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,0)  +0       +0       +x(1,0)  +0       +0       +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
0       +x(0,1)  +0       +0       +x(1,1)  +0       +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
0       +0       +x(0,2)  +0       +0       +x(1,2)  +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
```

The above equation can also be seen as:

```
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +x(1,0)  +x(2,0)  = 0
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +x(1,1)  +x(2,1)  = 0
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,0)  +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,0)  = 0
x(0,1)  +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,1)  = 0
x(0,2)  +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,0)  +x(1,0)  +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,1)  +x(1,1)  +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,2)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
```

For example, the given equation can have following two solutions:

1. x(0,2)=x(1,0)=x(1,1)=1 and all x(i,j) = 0. In this case sum of all x(i,j) = 3
2. x(2,2)=1 and all x(i,j)=0. In this case sum of all x(i,j) is 1

What algorithm can be used to find later solution. I have tried using gausian elimination, but the result is not consistent.

**More explanation:**
More explanation on how the equation was obtained: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/441588/299278

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another Stack Exchange site, probably math (where you obtained the equation in the first place).

Comment: But isn't it an algorithmic question?

Comment: Your "sum" is equivalent to a XOR operation. So you can simply use nested loops to check if the equations are all true, for all possible values of the unknown variables (use boolean type for the variables).

Comment: doesn't you want us to implement you homework or a competition project?

Comment: @salvador dali No, I am not trying to do anyone anything on my behalf.

Comment: @Laurent h. I was thinking the same thing. I am doing that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relabeling, the basis is

```
XOR(a, b, c, d,       g      ) = 0
XOR(a, b, c,    e,       h   ) = 0
XOR(a, b, c,       f,       i) = 1
XOR(a,       d, e, f, g      ) = 0
XOR(   b,    d, e, f,    h   ) = 0
XOR(      c, d, e, f,       i) = 1
XOR(a,       d,       g, h, i) = 1
XOR(   b,       e,    g, h, i) = 1
XOR(      c,       f, g, h, i) = 1
```

We can remove identical sub-phrases to find

```
# removing rows
XOR(d, g) = XOR(e, h) = NOT XOR(f, i)    # -(a, b, c)
XOR(a, g) = XOR(b, h) = NOT XOR(c, i)    # -(d, e, f)
XOR(a, d) = XOR(b, e) = XOR(c, f)        # -(g, h, i)
# removing columns
XOR(b, c) = XOR(e, f) = NOT XOR(h, i)    # -(a, d, g)
XOR(a, c) = XOR(d, f) = NOT XOR(g, i)    # -(b, e, h)
XOR(a, b) = XOR(c, e) = XOR(g, h)        # -(c, f, i)
```

If we sum all our basis rules and reduce - remember, `XOR(a, a) = 0` - we find

```
XOR(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) = 1
```

that is, any solution must contain an odd number of 1s: 1, 3, 5, or 7 (we can trivially discard 9 as it must contradict all of our basis rules which result in 0).

Let's try to find a solution containing only one 1:

- if either d or g is 1, then e or h must be 1; this gives us a minimum of two 1s, which contradicts our goal. So d, g, e, h must all be 0 and f or i must be 1.
- by the same argument a, g, b, h are 0 and c or i is 1.
- by the same argument a, d, b, e, c, f are 0
- obviously i must be 1
- checking back, this is a consistent solution, and the only solution containing a single 1.

More generally - if we assume values are given for a, b, c, d, e:

```
f = XOR(b, c, e)
g = XOR(a, b, c, d)
h = XOR(a, b, c, e)
i = NOT XOR(a, e)
```

which allows us to easily generate all possible solutions:

```
from itertools import product

tests = [
    lambda a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i: a ^ b ^ c ^ d ^ g == 0,
    lambda a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i: a ^ b ^ c ^ e ^ h == 0,
    lambda a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i: a ^ b ^ c ^ f ^ i == 1,
    lambda a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i: a ^ d ^ e ^ f ^ g == 0,
    lambda a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i: b ^ d ^ e ^ f ^ h == 0,
    lambda a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i: c ^ d ^ e ^ f ^ i == 1,
    lambda a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i: a ^ d ^ g ^ h ^ i == 1,
    lambda a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i: b ^ e ^ g ^ h ^ i == 1,
    lambda a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i: c ^ f ^ g ^ h ^ i == 1
]

sols = []
for a, b, c, d, e in product([0,1], repeat=5):
    f = b ^ c ^ e
    g = a ^ b ^ c ^ d
    h = a ^ b ^ c ^ e
    i = 1 - (a ^ e)
    if all(test(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) for test in tests):
        sols.append(
            "{}   {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}"
            .format(sum([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]), a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
        )
sols.sort()
print("\n".join(sols))
```

which gives

```
1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
3   0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
3   0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
3   1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
3   1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
5   0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
5   0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
5   0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
5   0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
5   0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
5   1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
5   1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
5   1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
5   1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
7   1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
7   1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

Note that exactly half the generated solutions pass testing; this strongly suggests it should be possible to make one more variable dependent, but I haven't found a way to do so yet.

---

**Edit:** After further reading, we can represent our basis as an augmented matrix,

```
a b c d e f g h i x
-------------------
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

After performing Gaussian reduction, we get

```
a b c d e f g h i x
-------------------
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0     #
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0     # under-constrained - multiple solutions
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0     #
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0     #
```

If we assign arbitrary values to `a..e` we end up with

```
f g h i  x
-----------
1 0 1 0  a
1 1 0 0  b
1 1 1 1 1-c
1 1 0 1 1-d
1 0 1 1 1-e    # over-constrained! Some choices of a..e will not work
```

which is exactly what I previously concluded, but achieved in a much more generally applicable way.

From this point you can plug in every combination of `a..e` and again use Gaussian reduction to find solutions for `f..i`, or solving symbolically gets you

```
f g h i  x
-----------
1 0 0 0  a ^ (1-c) ^ (1-d)
0 1 0 0  a ^ b ^ (1-c) ^ (1-d)
0 0 1 0  (1-c) ^ (1-d)
0 0 0 1  b ^ (1-d)
0 0 0 1  a ^ (1-e)      # over-constrained!
```

The over-constraint is actually useful here; note that `b ^ (1-d) == a ^ (1-e)` so `e` can be found as a function of `a, b, d`. So:

```
from itertools import product

for a,b,c,d in product([0,1], repeat=4):
    e = a ^ b ^ d
    f = a ^ c ^ d
    g = a ^ b ^ c ^ d
    h = c ^ d
    i = b ^ (1-d)
    print(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
```

which produces

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: This make sense perfectly. I am trying to extend this for input with n number of variables

Comment: The solution is not efficient if number of variable is increased

Comment: @h_t: I was going to say that this sort of problem is NP-complete; that is true of general Boolean satisfiability problems, but apparently xor-only problems can be solved by Gaussian reduction in O(n**3) time: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#XOR-satisfiability  To find all solutions, or the least-1s solution, is a bit harder; I will try to do an example later this morning.